# C# - What will I miss if I start with .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#

I got a book named "Pro C# 2005 and the .NET 2.0 Platform, Third Edition by Andrew Troelsen".
I am wondering whether I should buy the "Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform, Fifth Edition" instead. Since, the latest version of .NET is 4.0. If I learn C# based on this old book, do I miss some critical parts of the C# language? Or, I can start with this book and learn new .NET 4.0 features with other resources.

Thank you

Comment: you'll miss the pain of appreciation

Comment: By Troelsen?  Both are excellent books!

Comment: You'll miss how computers came into being and the history of fortran. When designing applications today, it is very important to know how computers came about. I say you start with fortran 101.

Comment: @user: starting with Fortran? _Please_. There was [plenty of programming before Fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_computing_2400_BC%E2%80%931949).

Comment: @Bears.... I am not THAT old !! :-P

Comment: I learnt C# from "Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform, Fourth Edition" (it's the book my university lecturer suggested). It's a pretty good book so I guess the 2005 and 2010 ones would be good too.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can start with that book and learn C# 4.0 from elsewhere. This is what's been added after C# 2.0:

[**C# 3.0**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_3.0):

- [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQ)
- lambdas
- extension methods
- expression trees
- anonymous types
- local type inferencing
- automatic properties
- object initializers
- collection initializers
- partial methods

[**C# 4.0**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_4.0)

- dynamic member lookup
- covariant and contravariant generic type parameters
- optional parameters and named arguments
- parallelization framework (actually part of .NET 4, not C# 4.0 *per se*)

Comment: C# 4 and the corresponding CLR also adds the ability to "link in" type information from Primary Interop Assemblies so that you do not have to ship the PIA with your application. (PIA assemblies are frequently large and irritating to have to ship if you're only using a couple of methods in them.) Of course, this is more of a compiler feature than a language feature.

Comment: Don't forget WPF, WCF etc.  Although not language features, they are important parts of .Net which have been added since 2.0.

Comment: A few extra things for C# 4: Some other COM improvements (pseudo-ref parameters), event and locking changes. Also, the parallelization framework isn't part of C# 4, it's part of .NET 4.

Comment: I added your note about the parallelization framework—I just thought it'd be worth knowing about while learning C# 4.0

Comment: One thing I'd add to this, is that a lot of things out there explaining the changes with 3 and 4 assume a good working knowledge of 2. Hence reading the book the querant has will put him in position to learn the rest more easily from the web or another book. 3 and 4 are still young enough that learning 2 won't lead to bad habits, and there is still enough 2 and 1.1 running code out there that knowing what came when is useful in itself.

Answer (score 24):

You will miss a lot. Most notably in my opinion, Linq.  Linq changes the whole face of idiomatic C# so much that I could not reccommend starting with the old book.

Comment: If I understood correctly, LINQ is related to Database and I seldomly use database through my projects. -- thank you

Comment: LINQ has nothing to do with databases.  You can use it with databases, but it is not directly linked with them.

Comment: @q0987: You understood wrong.  You are thinking of LinqToSql most likely.  Linq in its entirety is a much larger subject that is probably most frequently used without ever touching any database.

Comment: @q0987: LINQ is related to ordering, grouping, filtering and transforming data, whether it is data in a database, an array, an XML document, a web site, whatever. Do you do any ordering, grouping, filtering or transforming of data in your work? If yes, you might want to look into LINQ even if you don't use databases. (If not... what *do* you do with your data? Is it already perfect when you get it? That must be nice.)

Comment: @q0987, not true.  LINQ is a query language, yes, but it can be used on collections like arrays and lists as well, which saves you A LOT of work.

Comment: @q0987: LINQ *can* be related to databases... but certainly doesn't have to be. It's a *huge* boon whenever you're dealing with collections of data. Idiomatic C# 3 code is often *very* different to idiomatic C# 2 code.

Comment: Well, it's not specifically tied to databases—it's more like a new (and better) way to access data from collections.

Comment: You're thinking of LINQ-to-SQL. LINQ-to-objects alone is well worth knowing, but LINQ goes beyond even those (e.g., LINQ-to-XML).

Comment: I would start with a .NET 4 book. There are so many changes improvements since .NET 2.

Comment: make sure you invest in those LINQ to SQL books, buy them by the dozen they'll be worth a pretty penny in years to come - like antiques. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/01/01/is-linq-to-sql-dead.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I think you will be missing out on LINQ, which is quite a notable addition. If you are open to other reccomendations, I would say try Jon Skeet's [C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/). It gives a very good coverage of the various changes in the language from versions 2.0 to 4.0 (I purchased the early access edition).

Comment: @Jon. I apologize for the misspelling of your name.

Comment: @Mike, correcting a case of "Jon" being mis-spelt as "John" is always a worthwhile edit IMO ;)

Answer (score 5):

Lambdas / LINQ are pretty huge.

Answer (score 3):

C# 2 has generics, and it's good, but C# 3 and 4 have LINQ and dynamic typing, respectively, both of which are very powerful in their respective milieus.

And that's just to name two. There's a crap-ton more in there that you're missing out on.

If you can, always develop against the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly start with C# 2.0 and learn the basics.  There are many great new features in C# 4.0, but many of them are advanced or what are called 'syntactic sugar' meaning it's a more terse way of writing something you could already do with C# 2.0.

There are many different posts about the new features you can reference, without buying a complete book on it:

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/080228.htm
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/cs2010samples

I'd reccommend not spending the money up front, and checking out what the interweb has to offer.

Comment: The 15seconds.com link seems mostly broken now. It goes to the codeguru.com homepage, rather than a specific article.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think 2.0 is the right version of C# to start with. If you're going to learn the language for the first time, then starting with 2.0 is totally fine. 2.0 is the major release of the *core* language.

From 3.0 some features have been added which are nothing but "*syntactic sugars*" and "*time/typing savers*", and which confuse beginners, and you're gonna have to post questions here like "*whether I should use constructors or object initializers*".

Of course, you'll not find the new features added in 3.0 and 4.0 in a book for 2.0. But just as you said, you can always be introduced with those from other resources.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend you start learning C# with such an old version.

If you have the money to buy the new edition you should go for it. There were a lot of changes since .net 2.0.

If buying a new book it's not possible for you at this moment you could start learning the basic stuff from that book and learn new features from online resources.

Comment: He doesn't need to spend any money. The Express Editions of Visual Studio 2010 are absolutely free, and provide full support for .NET 4.0.

Comment: Mike, maybe I wasn't clear enough but I was talking about buying a new book, not visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

You would miss most of the new technologies.
3.0 introduced WPF, WCF and WF
3.5 gave us LINQ, and other related techniques like lambda expressions, extension methods...
4.0 brought the DLR, for dynamic typing.

A full summary of new features can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework).

Answer (score 2):

LINQ isn't all you'll miss. A lot of technologies that were added to 3.0 *with* LINQ (and largely because of it) stand on their own merits and make it very worthwhile to adopt the latest version.

- Lambdas
- Anonymous Methods (might have been 2.0, can't remember at the moment)
- Type Inference
- Dynamic types in 4.0
- Lots of new classes and improvements

I think you might be doing yourself a disservice if you cripple yourself with 2.0 if you don't really *have* to. The Framework is, after all, free, and so is the online documentation. Further, online tutorials abound, and you hve a plentiful resource for programming advice right here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Anonymous functions did exist in the form of inline delegates, but the syntax was painful.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has a helpful set of pages (start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383815(v=VS.90).aspx)) that tell you exactly what you will be missing out on when you target older versions of C# and the .Net Framework.

Remember when you target a C# version you are not just tying yourself to the language but to the matching .Net Framework - there is a whole bunch of new stuff in 2008 and then again in 2010 that you will miss out on by going .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

The major things you will want to know about that have come along since 2.0 include:

- Linq (a powerful compiler-checked query language used for list/set processing and as an interface to ORM frameworks).
- Anonymous types and delegates (lambda expressions). Need to store a list of some data fields you've gotten from a Linq expression, but don't need/want to define a whole new type just to store them? You don't have to anymore. Similarly, if you need to do something to each element of a list, or specify some operation to return a result, but don't want to define a named method, you don't have to. C# allows you to specify "anonymous" types and delegates, which are defined where they are used and are accessible only through the variable containing the delegate or data reference.
- WPF (The next generation of UI development, it is an XML-based presentation layout definition that will EVENTUALLY replace WinForms and ASP.NET)
- WCF - the next generation of web service classes, supporting built-in security features like encryption.
- Microsoft Entity Framework - Microsoft's take on ORM frameworks like NHibernate
- Dynamic typing - C# 4.0 allows for relaxed type restrictions by defining types or parameters as `dynamic`. This allows .NET to interface more seamlessly with assemblies or native APIs written in "duck-typed" languages (where the type is always dynamic, inferred from what you're trying to do with the instance)
- Better covariance/contravariance support - .NET 4.0 allows you to specify that collections of a type can be treated as if they were a collection of a derived type, or an ancestor type.

Comment: Thank you for all these info. The bad news for me is that I have to buy a new book.

Answer (score 1):

The versions of .Net are all primarily similar, but the only thing you may glean by starting with 2.0 would be to get a history of where certain changes in the languages came from. That's more of an experience thing though. If you're not already trained in C#, it would be best to start at the very latest. The fundamentals of the language will still be the same. You'll also learn the latest techniques for accomplishing common tasks rather than learning an outdated method and then having to relearn it later and try to understand the differences and why it exists in the first place.

Start with the latest stuff. Don't learn from antiquated sources and then try to fill in the gaps with extraneous information.

Comment: You know, just the other day I was trying to remember what it was like to wire up event handlers in .NET 1.1 in C#. I couldn't find a single example anywhere. So you're right: it's good to have a grasp on "The Glory Days" so you can see where we've been, where we are, and where we might be going. And programming .NET is programming .NET. Eventually it all comes down to the compiler and the classes. But I think I'd still recommend adopting the latest version if I were in his shoes.

Comment: @Mike Hofer - I remember those days, and I'm sure MS still has some link-rotted document somewhere about it, but yah - latest stuff or bust.

Answer (score 1):

Programming technologies change so fast as it is, why would you invest time reading such an old book?  I'd get the newest one.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the aforementioned Linq/lambdas etc, the later books will also cover technologies such as WPF which has pretty much replaced winforms for desktop development, and WCF which is the common communications method now, so I'd try and get a later book.